# Other language word/string split/manipulation issue

Tags: c#, string, split, tamil

Highlight the text searched scenario:

Ex: If I have a word RK and 'r' is searched, I have to highlight first occurance of 'r' i.e., **R**K. In the background it is like

< b >R< /b >K.

Similarly I have to highlight ம in மொ. Hence I am trying to find the position of ம in மொ and performing highlighting operation. 
Here I am getting the text after manipulation as

< b >ம< /b >ொ and hence it is displayed as **ம** ொ

The code that I used for string manipulation and highlighting:

```
formattedString = string.Empty;
searchStringLength = searchString.Length;

formattedString += inputString.Substring(0, find);
formattedString += "<b>" + inputString.Substring(find, searchStringLength) + "</b>";
formattedString += inputString.Substring(find + searchStringLength);
```

The example is just for Tamil word, any suggestions to make it work for all other languages other than english?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know Tamil. Looking at your question, the input string should be three letter string.

Probably, you are setting your `find` variable something like

```
find = inputString.IndexOf("ம");?
```

somewhere in your code.

The Tamil word `மொ` is not being counted as three letter word. Visual Studio is handling it as single letter while `மொ.Length` returns 2. `ToCharArray()` also returns array of two characters. That is why, `IndexOf` is always returning 0.

Your comment on question:

> since ம + ொ = மொ, the ம find was returning true always. Now after this solution, ம find will return false and hence I don't have to highlight. Only if மொ is entered to find, it matches exactly and I can highlight.

I do not think problem is in `SubString`. The `IndexOf` needs to be handled tactically.